# Selecting Combinations of variables from DataFrame rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with 4 attributes each contains 2 variables.
{'A':[A1,A2],'B':[B1,B2],'C':[C1,C2],'D':[D1,D2]}

My Input DataFrame looks like this :

```
Date     A    B    C    D
  J1    A1   B1   C1   D1
  J1    A1   B2   C2   D1
  J1    A2   B2   C2   D2
  J1    A2   B1   C1   D2
  J2    A2   B1   C1   D2
  J2    A1   B1   C1   D1
```

The desired Outputs : 
4 DataFrames each contains a unique combination of variables (no matter the date value is).

**Output1: Combination A1, B1, C1, D1**

```
Date     A    B    C    D
  J1    A1   B1   C1   D1
  J2    A1   B1   C1   D1
```

**Output2: Combination A1, B2, C2, D1**

```
Date     A    B    C    D
  J1    A1   B2   C2   D2
```

**Output3: Combination A2, B2, C2, D2**

```
Date     A    B    C    D
  J1    A2   B2   C2   D2
```

**Output4: Combination A2, B1, C1, D2**

```
Date     A    B    C    D
  J1    A2   B1   C1   D2
  J2    A2   B1   C1   D2
```

Comment: Are you manually specifying which 4 of the 16 combinations you want? Of if there were more combinations would you want to separate them also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store a variable number of variables. In this instance, you can use `groupby` to extract your unique groups:

```
res = {i: j[1] for i, j in enumerate(df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']), 1)}

print(res)

{1:   Date   A   B   C   D
    0   J1  A1  B1  C1  D1
    5   J2  A1  B1  C1  D1,

 2:   Date   A   B   C   D
    1   J1  A1  B2  C2  D1,

 3:   Date   A   B   C   D
    3   J1  A2  B1  C1  D2
    4   J2  A2  B1  C1  D2,

 4:   Date   A   B   C   D
    2   J1  A2  B2  C2  D2}
```